# Lightning "document.getElementBy()" functions not working on page load

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning, html

I'm trying to perform the following using pure Javascript without jQuery.
- I have a lightning component sitting in a record detail flexi-page.
- On Loading the record I use Lightning data service and set variables in a javascript controller from the data retrieved via LDS. Note I had an issue where the record was returning null on the record page load however I got around this with help from [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/214315/lightning-data-service-targetrecord-on-pageload)

With the variables I set in my Javascript controller I then want to write these as text to divs in my lightning component.  I have a clock which counts down and updates the HTML in a loop based on

```
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_countdown.asp
```

This all works as required. The one issue I'm having though is that when I load my record/page the clock does not load until I refresh the page. `document.getElementBy("mydiv").innerHTML ="Hello"` & other setter methods do not work on the page load.  I thought I could use the afterRender as per [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_renderers.htm) but I cannot get this to work.
If I check `document.readyState == "complete"` it returns true but my subsequent HTML writing does not appear.

I want my clock to appear when the page loads, not on a refresh. Should I not be able to do this via `document.getElementBy("mydiv")`.whatever or do I require jQuery?  I would not have thought jQuery was needed for this.

Comment: If you haven't already, familiarise yourself wit the [LockerService](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/security_code.htm). This intrudes in many situations and may be a cause of your problem. jQuery isn't needed and will not help. Suggest you start using your browser's JavaScript debugger to track down what is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use of `document.getElementBy...` is not supported across components.

> ## [DOM Access Containment](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/security_dom.htm)
>
> A component can only traverse the DOM and access elements created by a component in the same namespace. This behavior prevents the anti-pattern of reaching into DOM elements owned by components in another namespace.
>   Note
>
> > **Note**
> >     It’s an anti-pattern for any component to “reach into” another component, regardless of namespace. LockerService only prevents cross-namespace access. Your good judgment should prevent cross-component access within your own namespace as it makes components tightly coupled and more likely to break.

You shouldn't really be using any `document` methods for DOM access anyway. The lightning approach uses aura methods instead:

> #### Valid DOM Access
>
> The following methods are valid DOM access because the elements are created by c:domLocker.
>
> `cmp.getElements()`
>   Returns the elements in the DOM rendered by the component.
>
> `cmp.find()`
>   Returns the div and button components, identified by their aura:id attributes.
>
> `cmp.find("div1").getElement()`
>   Returns the DOM element for the div as c:domLocker created the div.
>
> `event.getSource().get("v.name")`
>   Returns the name of the button that dispatched the event; in this case, myButton.

Comment: Thanks Adrian & Amurag, I had initially been using component.set() to set text in my divs instead of document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML but this seemed to behave erratically/weird when I try to update it every second for example for a countdown clock. Sometimes it appeared to skip counts or get muddled up then sort itself out. Using "__.innerHTML" seemed to do this less.  Is there a away to set innerHTML on a comp other than component.set?  I note I can add and remove classes via $A.util.addClass type functions but for text I guess I have to use component.set() functions? Thanks.

Comment: @RedQueries Please do not ask entirely separate questions in the comments. If either of these questions answered what you asked above, then accept one as resolving your issue, indicating you have solved the problem you asked about. If you need to ask about something entirely different like that, post a separate question.

Comment: Hi, It's not a separate question. It's for the same enquiry. I want to write clock text therefore I want to find my element on page load and write to it's innerHTML/ text. If I use document.getElementBy("mydiv").innerHTML and write my text this way it works fine except for the req for the initial page refresh. If I use component.set() this has performed strangely when testing this previously. I want to find a solution which works for a clock countdown updating every second. If I can't use document.getElementBy("mydiv").innerHTML and require component.find() do I then need to use component.set?

Comment: Thanks for your help Adrian, I didn't mean to offend on your answer. Both answers provided partly answer but are not a complete solution for my problem.  I didn't know whether to add a comment or an answer to this thread but the additional detail on somponent.set is not an answer so I added it as a comment.

Comment: I take no offense. The thing is, you are trying to ask something completely different than what you originally posted. The detail you added in the comment isn't even the same type of end goal as what you initially posted. Hence, it should really be a different question. Radically changing your post after there are answers tends to make it difficult to assist you.

Comment: I guess I'll have to phrase my questions better. It's difficult with the character limits. My dev solution has come full circle with this thread. I previously used component.set to try to set my params but when it was acting erratically sometimes because of seemingly struggling to cope with being updated every second I then moved away from this to trying to write to HTML, then encountered the refresh requirement issue on pageload so opened this question. If Locker service requires not using document.getelementbyId then I guess I'll need to go back to Component functions even if it struggles.

Answer (score 2):

With the locker service update, lightning has stopped supporting some Javsscript functions and objects. To refer a DOM elements. it should be `component.find()` instead of `document.getelementbyId`

Example:

```
<lightning:button aura:id="button1" label="button1"/>
```

You can find the component by calling `cmp.find("button1")`

[image]

Refer the link: http://shashankshastri.com/lightning-lockerservice/

Comment: Please include references as *text*, not images. Images do not give any search-ability or support for screen readers.

Comment: FYI the docs no longer explicitly mention `document.getElementById`, so your reference is outdated.

Comment: Yes @AdrianLarson, I added the link below screenshot where the text lies. But that's a good suggestion. Thank you.